# time difference's seems like working odd?

Tags: datetime, time, c++builder

I am going to find difference between two times but I am not getting what I want!!!
I have 2 timeEdit components in a form 
here is my code:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TTime time1=StrToTime(t1->Text);
    TTime time2=StrToTime(t2->Text);


    //t1->Text=time2-StrToTime("3:00");

    ShowMessage((time2-time1).TimeString());   
}
```

If I set t1 = 02:00
and set  t2 = 01:00

it shows 1:00

but I expect 23:00
that is 01:00  - 02:00  should be 23:00

where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not taking into account how `TTime` is encoded.  `TDateTime` is a `Double`, where the integral portion contains the number of days since Dec 30 1899, and the fractional portion contains a **percentage of a 24-hour day** (this information is stated in the C++Builder documentation). `TTime` is just the fractional portion of a `TDateTime` with its integral portion ignored. Because of this encoding, performing such seemingly simple mathematical operations on date/time values does not usually produce the kind of result you are expecting.

`02:00` (2 AM) is represented as `0.083333333333`, and `01:00` (1 AM) is represented as `0.041666666667`.  You are subtracting 2 AM from 1 AM, expecting it to subtract 2 hours to produce 11 PM (which is represented as `0.958333333333333`). Subtracting `0.083333333333` from `0.041666666667` produces `-0.041666666667`.  Ignoring the integral portion (the date), the fractional portion is a positive value from `0.0` (midnight), so `-0.041666666667` is equivilent to `0.041666666667`, which is 1 AM.

In order for your subtraction to work correctly, the starting time needs a positive integral portion (date) attached to it so the result contains the correct fractional portion, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TTime t = (1.0 + StrToTime("01:00")) - StrToTime("02:00");
    // (1.0 + 0.041666666667) - 0.083333333333
    // = 1.041666666667 - 0.083333333333
    // = 0.95833333333
    ShowMessage(t.TimeString());
}
```

Comment: Trying to compile this code .... Oops! an error occured                       [BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(63): E2015 Ambiguity between '_fastcall operator System::Variant::-(int) const at c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\vcl\sysvari.h:543' and '_fastcall operator System::Variant::-(double) const at c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\7.0\include\vcl\sysvari.h:565'
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(62): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(System::TObject *)

Comment: Converting to Double helped!! TTime t = (1.0 + double(StrToTime("01:30")) - StrToTime("08:50") );